# Firebase FEventTypeChildAdded callback gets called multiple times for the same new object

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, authentication, firebase

I am working on an iOS app and I have built my project on top of Firebase's login-demo app. I can authenticate with Facebook, and communicate with Firebase just fine. When I press the logout button, this is the code that is run:

```
- (void)logoutButtonPressed
{
     // logout of Firebase and set the current user to nil
     [self.simpleLogin logout];
     [self.ref unauth]; //Added this
     [self updateUIAndSetCurrentUser:nil];
     [self.items removeAllObjects];
     [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

And it appears to do the trick. Everything resets and my tableView is cleared. When I log back in, I get the data associated with my FB credentials and it populates and everything is great. I have a textField and a button and when I push the button the textField's text gets saved to firebase and updates locally.

**The problem** comes when I try and make a new entry to my simple list of strings after I have logged out once already. When I log back in, and try and save an entry, it gets saved to firebase once (which is correct), but my callback gets called twice!

```
[ref observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
            // Add the chat message to the array.
            if (![snapshot.value isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
                [self.items addObject:snapshot.value[@"text"]];
            }

            // Reload the table view so the new message will show up.
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        } withCancelBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
        }];
```

The same object snapshot shows up in this block twice, which means the same objects gets added twice to the array and my tableView. It gets even more strange if I logout and back in again. The third time, three copies show up. The fourth time, four items, etc. Here is the code for when I push the add button:

```
- (IBAction)submitButtonPressed {
    if ([self.currentUser.provider isEqualToString:@"facebook"]) {
    Firebase *postRef = [[[self.ref childByAppendingPath:@"users"] childByAppendingPath:self.currentUser.uid] childByAppendingPath:@"posts"];

    NSString *statusText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Logged in as %@ (Facebook)",
                  self.currentUser.providerData[@"displayName"]];

    [[postRef childByAutoId] setValue:@{@"name" : statusText, @"text": self.textField.text}];
    }
}
```

It seems like I may not be completely logging out of Firebase or FB, but I don't know what else to try.

What would cause the FEventTypeChildAdded callback to get called multiple times for the same new object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've never used the Firebase iOS SDK, but it most likely works in a similar way to the other SDKs.

If that is the case, the listener block that you registered, stays registered when the user logs out. Then when the user logs in again, you are registering a second event listener. So from that moment on, your code block will execute twice for every added child.

You should unregister/cancel the event listeners when the user logs out (https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/api/#firebase_removeAllObservers) or simply not re-register them again if you've already registered them before.

See the Firebase guide for iOS, specifically the section on detaching blocks: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-detaching

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem. I could have sworn I read through all of that documentation, looks like I missed some. Thanks so much. I'll award the bounty as soon as I can (16 hrs)