# Why is Firebase returning the same value twice when querying?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I am trying to query Firebase using the following query:

```
Firebase *refReplies = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:kFirebaseURLReplies];
[[[refReplies queryOrderedByChild:kChildKey] queryEqualToValue:kQueryValue] observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded
                                                                                               withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
                                                                                                   NSLog(@"reply key:%@",snapshot.key);
                                                                                               }];
```

When I run this I get the correct values, but every value is returned twice and I'm not sure why. I get something in my console log looking like this:

```
2015-08-20 14:06:35.220 AppName[1234:5678910] reply key:-keyName1
2015-08-20 14:06:35.221 AppName[1234:5678910] reply key:-keyName1
2015-08-20 14:06:35.221 AppName[1234:5678910] reply key:-keyName2
2015-08-20 14:06:35.222 AppName[1234:5678910] reply key:-keyName2
2015-08-20 14:06:35.222 AppName[1234:5678910] reply key:-keyName3
2015-08-20 14:06:35.223 AppName[1234:5678910] reply key:-keyName3
```

I also run a similar query somewhere else and the same thing happens. I could just ignore any duplicates snapshots, which for my purposes would be relatively simple, but that's just a work-around and I'm looking for a solution.

I also looked at this question: [Firebase FEventTypeChildAdded callback gets called multiple times for the same new object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28662913/firebase-feventtypechildadded-callback-gets-called-multiple-times-for-the-same-n). However, this solution won't solve my problem, considering that my app ALWAYS returns two values, no matter how many times I try to "re-login" or add another observation event.

Comment: Do you call `removeAllObservers` anwhere? https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/api/#firebase_removeAllObservers

Comment: I didn't think that this was the problem, but apparently it was. Very simple, thank you @frank. Add your comment as an answer and I'll check it off if you'd like. As a quick extra question, if I call `removeAllObservers` on my database generally (my base URL), will that remove every observer I have for Geofire and otherwise? Or do I have to use `removeAllObservers` for every Firebase URL which `observeEventType:withBlock:` has been called? Thanks for your help.

Comment: `removeAllObersers` removes the observers for all events on that location. You'll need to call it for each locaiton.